# Get value of DropDownList within Input tag

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core MVC application, I am using a DropDownList, which has fixed values. I am not using DropDownListFor and no binding with model.

I want to pick the selected text of this DropDownList and pass to the JS function as parameter. The same way as I am passing ID below.

```
       @foreach (TemplateData sheet in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@sheet.ID</td>
                <td>@sheet.Warehouse</td>
                <td>@sheet.Observation</td>
                <td>@sheet.EmpName</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("Work Status", new List<SelectListItem>
                  {
                     new SelectListItem{ Text="", Value = "0" },
                     new SelectListItem{ Text="Completed", Value = "1" },
                     new SelectListItem{ Text="InProgress", Value = "2" },
                     new SelectListItem{ Text="UnderReview", Value = "3" },
                  })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="btnSubmit" value="Update Status" class="ids" data-id="@sheet.ID" onClick="sendId(@sheet.ID)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current text through the `onchange` event.

```
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $("#Work_Status").on("change", function ()
    {
        var e = document.getElementById("Work_Status");
        var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var value = Work_Status.value;
    });
</script>
 }
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: When I am putting alert after var = value ...., it is showing undefined

Comment: Code used:   function ddlVal() {
        var e = document.getElementById('DDLStatus').innerHTML;
            var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            var value = DDLStatus.value;
            alert(value);
        };

Comment: Check if the name of your drop-down list is correct.